# Await iterating a datatable with awaitable methods

Tags: vb.net, asynchronous, datatable, async-await, datarow

I have the following Async Method, that awaits separate methods on a per row babsis.  I cannot for the life of me figure out how to take this to the next level, and await the whole datatable to be process (i.e have all rows start start together, instead of one at a time).  Any help would be much appreciated.

```
    Public Async Function GetLabResultPanelPackByPRN_Async(ByVal ClientID As Integer, ByVal PRN As Integer, ByVal SamplePointID As Integer, ByVal StartDate As DateTime, ByVal EndDate As DateTime, ByVal InequalityMode As InequalityModes) As Task(Of List(Of LabResultPanelPack))
    Dim LRPPs As New List(Of LabResultPanelPack)
    Dim ta As New eniCIP_DataTableAdapters.proc_WebPortal_ResultsByPRNTableAdapter
    Dim dt As New eniCIP_Data.proc_WebPortal_ResultsByPRNDataTable
    ta.Fill(dt, PRN)
    For Each row As eniCIP_Data.proc_WebPortal_ResultsByPRNRow In dt
        Dim LRPP As New LabResultPanelPack
        LRPP.LabResult = GetLabResultByPRNFromRow(row, InequalityMode)

        Dim ResultsByDetAndSPTask As Task(Of List(Of LabResultExtended)) = GetResultsByDetAndSP_Async(ClientID, SamplePointID, row.lDetID, StartDate, EndDate, InequalityMode)
        Dim ResultsBySampleTypeAndDetTask As Task(Of List(Of LabResultExtended)) = GetResultsBySampleTypeAndDet_Async(ClientID, row.lSampleTypeID, row.lDetID, StartDate, EndDate, InequalityMode)
        Dim ResultsBySampleTypeGroupAndDetTask As Task(Of List(Of LabResultExtended)) = GetResultsBySampleTypeGroupAndDet_Async(ClientID, row.lSampleTypeGroupID, row.lDetID, StartDate, EndDate, InequalityMode)

        LRPP.HistoricResultsByDetAndSP = Await ResultsByDetAndSPTask
        LRPP.HistoricResultsByDetAndSampleType = Await ResultsBySampleTypeAndDetTask
        LRPP.HistoricResultsByDetAndSampleTypeGroup = Await ResultsBySampleTypeGroupAndDetTask

        LRPPs.Add(LRPP)
    Next

    Return LRPPs
End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in this case is simply adding a function and things clear up quickly.

If you create a new function that handles the processing of *one* row like so:

```
Private Async Function ProcessRow(row As YourRowType, ...) As Task(Of LabResultPanelPack)
  Dim LRPP As New LabResultPanelPack
  LRPP.LabResult = GetLabResultByPRNFromRow(row, InequalityMode)

  'Add your tasks for processing the row further
  Return LRPP
End Function
```

Now your main loop looks something like this:

```
For Each row As eniCIP_Data.proc_WebPortal_ResultsByPRNRow In dt
  Dim LRPP = Await ProcessRow(row, ...)
  LRPPs.Add(LRPP)
Next
```

And at this point you can change your `LRPPs` list to

```
Dim LRPPTasks As New List(Of Task(Of LabResultPanelPack))
```

And change your loop to

```
For Each row As eniCIP_Data.proc_WebPortal_ResultsByPRNRow In dt
  Dim LRPPTask = ProcessRow(row, ...)
  LRPPTasks.Add(LRPPTask)
Next
```

This way you avoid waiting for every row and processing the rows continues as soon as the first `await` inside the `ProcessRow` function is reached.

All you need to do at the end is change your return to

```
Return Await Task.WhenAll(LRPPTasks)
```

And your are done.

Just as a small addition: After rewriting the code as I suggested, you would end up with the only `Await` in the `Function`. This means that you could remove the `Async` flag from the function and the `Await` from the `Return`. This way you get a little less overhead.

Comment: Nitram, thank you for going to so much effort, works a treat!